# 2-D laplace heat equation with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, numpy

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1vy5.png)**I'm trying to implement periodic condition for horizontal direction, I discretized laplace equation bottom temperature is high, at the top temperature is zero and also left and right side **

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set maximum iteration
maxIter = 500
lenX = lenY = 20 #we set it rectangular
delta = 1
# Boundary condition
Ttop = 0
Tbottom = 9.75
Tright = 0
Tleft = 0
# Initial guess of interior grid
Tguess = (Ttop + Tbottom)/2 
colorinterpolation = 50
colourMap = plt.cm.jet #you can try: colourMap = plt.cm.coolwarm
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, lenX), np.arange(0, lenY))#,indexing='ij')
T = np.empty((lenX, lenY))+ np.random.random((lenX,lenY))
T.fill(Tguess)
T[(lenY-1):, :] = Ttop
T[:1, :] = Tbottom
T[:, (lenX-1):] = Tright
T[:, :1] = Tleft
for iteration in range(0, maxIter):
for i in range(1, lenX-1, delta):
for j in range(1, lenY-1, delta):
 T[i, j] = 0.125 * (T[i+1][j] + T[i-1][j] + T[i][j+1] + T[i][j-1] - 4*T[i,j]) + T[i,j]
plt.contourf(X, Y, T, colorinterpolation, cmap=colourMap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[I'm getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvOn3.png)

Comment: What's expected result? Or the error you get? Or where exactly did you get stuck? Your question is too broad..narrow it down to specific problem.

Comment: The code is for simple 2-D heat diffusion, I wanted to implement  horizontal direction is periodic.

Comment: It still is too narrow. Give some background on the theory behind it. Is your question really [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here?

Comment: If you set a B.C. of zero on the left and right edges it seems correct to me that you get that temperature on those edges (as in your output)

Comment: I am trying to simulate the temperature variation in a cavity without boundary, so that gradient of temperature is seen only in vertical direction.